# Testing viewmodel with coroutines, LiveData, and a repo

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I am trying to setup my first test for a pretty straight forward project. But it does involve coroutines and LiveDatas, I keep getting either an error about the Main Looper not being mocked, or that the assertion is not correct since no value is in the livedata which is accessible to the test.

Any comments to fix and/or improve the test are welcome!

The project has a view model with a `fetchData()` (full code further down). in it, it calls the repo inside a `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {... repo.fetchData() ...}`
Whenever the data comes back and stored in a local var, then inside `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {...}` I call `postValue` on the MutableLiveData<>.

Here is the view model fetchData:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   try {
        val localList = dataRepo.fetchData()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
          _data = localList
          data.postValue(_data)
        }
      } catch (throwable: Throwable) {...}
}
```

Now the test file. My strategy was to test when `fetchData()` is called, then the data is populated. I am sending a fake repo to the viewmodel, thus avoiding network calls.
It seems to fail in a few points, the current one if the data not getting populated.

From what I understand, there are 2 problem areas that keep failing. Either the coroutine, and the Dispatchers. When I do `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) is gave that Looper error, but that seemed to not appear with the current code. The second is that the last assertion (that the list is not empty) is false, probably connected to the LiveData not getting triggered.

Problem solving (aka. things I tried):

1. Adding `@get:Rule val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()` which comes with a class that calls on `Dispatchings.setMain()` etc... pattern is in many locations, so seems legit.
2. Adding `@get:Rule var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()` so make the observable fire
3. Adding `viewModel.data.observeForever {}` right before I call `fetchData()` which is where the LiveData does it's `postValue`
4. Adding `testDispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()` for the same reason as #3, didn't matter.

Here's the full test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DataViewModelTest {

  @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
  @get:Rule val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

  @get:Rule var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
  //  @Mock private lateinit var context: Context
  //  @Mock private lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
  val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
  @Before
  fun setUp() {
//    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)

  }
  @After fun tearDown() {}
  @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
  @Test
  fun `dataViewModel_network fetch call_success populate the list`() = runTest {
    val viewModel = DataViewModel(DataFakeRepoImpl())
    assert(viewModel.data.value != null)
    assert(viewModel.data.value!!.isEmpty())
    //viewModel.data.observeForever {}
    testDispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()
    viewModel.fetchData()
    assert(viewModel.data.value!!.isNotEmpty())
  }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class MainDispatcherRule(
    private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher(),
) : TestWatcher() {
  override fun starting(description: Description) {
    super.starting(description)
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
  }

  override fun finished(description: Description) {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
    super.finished(description)
  }
}
```

Not sure what's the next step or what else to try. Or even if my approach is completely off...